# Retag + synonym [systray] => [notification-area]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

Could we have [systray](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/systray) (4 Qs) made a synonym of [notification-area](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/notification-area) (19 Qs)?

At least [according to Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030910-00/?p=42583), the correct name is "(Taskbar) Notification Area", so the [systray](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/systray) tag is incorrect. They are currently being used for the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
updating post history, 4 rows affected
updating posts, 4 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 4 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [notification-area] and [systray] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym systray -> notification-area was approved!
```

done!